# Angular UI Grid - Configure menu items globally for all columns

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I know I can configure ui-grid to show extra menu items on a per column basis, such as the following.

```
 $scope.gridOptions = {

    "data": "results.values",
    "columnDefs": [
    { "name": "Employee Number",
      "field": "emp_no",
      "menuItems":[
          {
              "title":"Sort All Asc",
              "action":function(){console.log('test')}
          }
      ]
    }
   ]
}
```

Is there any way I can do this not in the columnDefs property, so that an item will be applied to all columns?

Comment: do you want a custom grid menu that will be applied on selected rows?

Comment: Correct, but I do not want to put it in the columnDefs property as I have in my question. I would like to configure the menuItems property once so it applies to every column in the grid.

Comment: last question - you mean one menu for the whole grid?

Comment: Ask as many as you need. No, I would like menus above each column, as is the default with the sorting, and hide column option. I can accomplish what I need to do, I am just trying to avoid having to specify the same menu items for every column I have. I would like to have one menuItems property in my gridOptions, and that property to apply to each menu above each column. In my example in my question, if I were to define more columns I would have to add the menuItems property for those columns as well. (which would be the same)

Answer (score 0):

After you specify your gridOptions, you can do the following

```
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs.length; i++) {
    $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs[i].menuItems = yourMenuItemsArray;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I am really looking for a way where I don't need any JavaScript code whatsoever. I think I am out of luck, it doesn't look like they support it yet.